# Aligning images using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to align these images using flex box like so..

[image]

Currently the images look like so..

[image]

I tried using 'align-self' applied to the elements that need to be on the bottom row however it did not move much.

This is what I currently have:

```css
.clover-items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.clover-items .clover-items__container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="clover-items">
    <div class="clover-items__container">
        <img src="assets/images/cart_icon.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="icon_title">Over 100 business apps</h4>

        <img src="assets/images/check_mark_icon.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="icon_title">Real time reporting</h4>

        <img src="assets/images/check_icon.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="icon_title">Fast access to funds</h4>

        <img src="assets/images/lock_icon.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="icon_title">Card data is secure</h4>

        <img src="assets/images/person_icon.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="icon_title">U.S. Based 24/7 customer service</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap.?

Comment: @FranklinPious no, no bootstrap

Comment: Break them into two div tags instead, and use clover items container as a separate class

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky layout with flexbox because once `wrap` is activated the items can wrap anytime. So even if you achieve the layout you want at one screen size, it may break on smaller screens. It can be done, but you would need to substantially alter the HTML.

Here's a demo with a slight modification to the HTML (nested containers). The layout works on wide screens, but fails on small screens. [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7881331/2/)

Here's a simple solution with CSS Grid: [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7881331/1/)

```css
.clover-items__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "top-one top-one top-one top-two top-two top-two"
               "bottom-one bottom-one bottom-two bottom-two bottom-three bottom-three";
}

.clover-items__container > div:nth-child(1) { grid-area: top-one; }
.clover-items__container > div:nth-child(2) { grid-area: top-two; }
.clover-items__container > div:nth-child(3) { grid-area: bottom-one; }
.clover-items__container > div:nth-child(4) { grid-area: bottom-two; }
.clover-items__container > div:nth-child(5) { grid-area: bottom-three; }

.clover-items__container > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.clover-items__container > div > h4 {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clover-items__container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
    <h4 class="icon_title">Over 100 business apps</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
    <h4 class="icon_title">Real time reporting</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
    <h4 class="icon_title">Fast access to funds</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
    <h4 class="icon_title">Card data is secure</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="25" height="25" alt="">
    <h4 class="icon_title">U.S. Based 24/7 customer service</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `flex-wrap:wrap;`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

If you set `padding` or `margin` to first two images and apply flex wrap property this can be performed.